# SSAS - what could I monitor in SSAS to fine tune its memory settings?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, memory, configuration, ssas

This question is a follow up from the 
[SSAS - what could be a good starting point for memory settings?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115347/ssas-what-could-be-a-good-starting-point-for-memory-settings)

What and **how** can I monitor the server resources in order to best identify the settings that I should apply to my SSAS instance?

In this case we're talking about sql server 2014, and the server is a windows server 2012, with the spect below

[image]

Comment: Check out the SSAS specific DMVs which can help you isolate a user, measure etc. issue. Also, avoid storing string data in a cube... it will consume memory at a fantastic rate and doesn't benefit from the aggregation centric design of SSAS.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230820.aspx

Comment: Are you still wanting help? Are you wanting perfmon counters to monitor overall memory usage by SSAS? Something else? This blog post talks about SSAS memory use and it's use of the file system cache: http://www.artisconsulting.com/blogs/greggalloway/2010/12/29/analysis-services-and-the-case-of-the-standby-cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to fine-tune your memory settings there are two things you'd want to watch:

1. MSOLAP Memory counters for your server in Performance monitor

[image]

2. Specific DMV queries over discover_object_memory_usage rowset and discover_object_activity rowset.

You can always use a [third-party tool](https://www.google.rs/search?q=bi%20monitoring%20tools) to monitor your resources. Also, you might want to check out [this article](http://byobi.com/2014/04/ssas-memory-configurations-for-common-architectures/) – it gives a detailed description on how to achieve exactly what you are looking for.